# How set the background image to selected state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the following script to change the position of my background image of the  tags in my menu items when it hovers.But I can't figure out a way to set the background position for the selected state. can you please help me.

This is the script I have used.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav_main li a').hover(function () {
       height = $(this).height() * (-1);
       $(this).stop().animate({'backgroundPosition':'(0 ' + height + ')'}, {duration:300}); 
}, function () {  
    $(this).stop().animate({'backgroundPosition':'(0 0)'}, {duration:300}); 
    }         
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "selected state" ?

Comment: for example think we are in the home page.when the home page is selected, I want the background position of that menu item to be as in the 

"$(this).stop().animate({'backgroundPosition':'(0 ' + height + ')'}, {duration:300});"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to hscripts css tutorial page to learn how to set a background image for selected items in a list. http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/css/backp3.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a selected page information, for example if you are in the folder `/home/index.php` you can get the variable `$folder = 'home';` in php.
then you set on all the menu items special class like *myMenuItem-home* when you arrive on home folder you have a jquery like this:

```
$('.myMenuItem-'+folder).stop().animate(
    {'backgroundPosition':'(0 '+($('.myMenuItem-'+folder).height() * (-1))+')'}, {duration:300});
```

Comment: When it is selected background position should be 
({'backgroundPosition':'(0 ' + height + ')'}

IS there any other way of achieving this even by changing the css would be fine. 
thank you!